# Create a flow where client pays freelancer

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I am creating an app where clients connect with freelancers and send them money!

I am currently thinking of using Paypal as my Payment Integration.

My question is: Is it possible to create a flow where the client pays the freelancer directly, without my server being a broker?

Also, are there better solutions than PayPal!

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) with a `payee` parameter to [pay another account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/).